# don't get return associative array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array, key-value

When i create associate array in javascript, i got a problem like that.
I want to get the value by using field name as key, but i just only got undefined.
What should i do to get value by key or which way is good approach for it.

Here is my code

```
function getFields(pVal){
    var tmpObj = {};
    str = pVal.split(",");
    for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        tmpVal = str[i].split(":");
        tmpObj[tmpVal[0]] = tmpVal[1];  
    }
    return tmpObj;
}

function JustTest(){
   var fields = {}; 
   fields = getFields("'Code':'PRJ001','Name':'Project 01'");
   alert(fields['Code']);
}
```

Comment: Where is this string from? It _looks_ like it should be JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the key is `'Code'`, not `Code`, note the single quote `'`, you need do  `alert(fields["'Code'"]);`

***PS:*** Please add `;` at the end of statement, it is bad practice to omit them.

Comment: [semicolons are optional](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding)

Comment: prefixed semicolons are semicolons, so they are not optional.

Comment: when i create static object by using single code. i can retrieve value.  in dynamically, i can not get the value. may i know about the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-factor the code, just try this:

```
function getFields(pVal) {
    var tmpObj = {};
    var str = pVal.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var tmpVal = str[i].split(":");
        tmpObj[tmpVal[0]] = tmpVal[1];
    }
    return tmpObj;
}

function JustTest() {
    var fields = { };
    fields = getFields("'Code':'PRJ001','Name':'Project 01'");
    alert(fields["'Code'"]);
}
```

if you have question please comment below about code, thanks

Comment: i remove the single quote from parameters. because i can use 2 ways [fields['Code'] and fields.Code]